# Call function problems as3

Tags: function, actionscript-3, variables, parameter-passing, call

I'm calling a function from a child class and passing the current section variables for it to then load/remove the next section, everything works fine until I then try to pass the same variable to core function I used previously. I can't understand why it's not working again.

Problem with the following :

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method setupSection.

- Initially I setup the parameters and to load the class from a standard function :

  ```
  public function setupVariables():void {
      //Main code here

      //Establish Section 
      currentSection = secData;
      setupSection(currentSection);
  }

  public function setupSection(sectionHolder:String):void {
      //Here selects the right choice from an Array and loads new Section.
  }

  //I call the function from the child
  Main.changeSection("loadNext");


  public static function changeSection(lSection:String):void {
      var lSection : String;
      currentSection = lSection;

      trace("Val Passed = " +currentSection);
      //TraceOutput is - Val Passed = loadNext

      setupSection(currentSection);
  }

  public function setupSection(sectionHolder:String):void {
      //LoadSection etc. . .
  }
  ```

The offending command appears to be this :

```
setupSection(currentSection);
```

currentSection is a String set up previously.

I've used this previously and it worked fine but not from the static function.

If any one can shed some light on why this isn't working I'd be so grateful as I just can't get it to work.

Comment: You should re-think your design. Mixing static and non-static functions will always lead to trouble. Static properties and functions are instance-independent, meaning that an object of class `XYZ` doesn't need to have an instance to be able to access it's static properties/functions. Which in effect means, that you're trying to a call a function from nothing. Instead of a static function calls, why not dispatch an Event from your child class?

Comment: @DodgerThud - I'm possibly looking too hard at the problem as you say, it just seems irrational that a function which has been previously called from the main class can't be called via another function in the same code.

Dispatching an event I'm having trouble with but I'll look into it.

I want to control a master navigation from the main class to choose between key classes. Loading these key classes will have navigation for the separate classes and individual sections of each of these child classes. From each key class there is an option to just change between key classes. Not sure how.

Comment: `in the same code` you see, that's the problem, it isn't the same code. One is in a static context (globally available) and one is in an object context. I will try to write a more thorough explanation of the issue later today, when I'm off work.

Comment: @DodgerThud - Thanks, I've added some to explain better where and how I call it.

Comment: Your code is not formatted correctly, can you please fix it? Also what is the name of this "child class"?

Answer (score 0):

A static function cannot call an instance function. Static is essentially global and not associated with any instance of the class, so it can't call an instance function because it isn't an instance and has no idea what (if any) instances exist.

What you can do, if you really want to keep `changeSection()` as a static function, is to pass an instance of the class as an argument so that you can call `setupSection()` on the instance. Example:

```
public static function changeSection(lSection:String, main:Main):void { 
    var lSection : String; currentSection = lSection;

    trace("Val Passed = " +currentSection);
    //TraceOutput is - Val Passed = loadNext

    main.setupSection(currentSection);
}
```

And if you don't have easy access to an instance of the class when calling the function, what you are trying to do is more like a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). In this case you need to store a static reference to your single instance, so that you can easily access it from anywhere. Then you only need instance functions, and you call those through the static reference to the instance. For example:

```
class Main {
    public static var main:Main;
    public var currentSection:String;
    public function Main() {
        main = this;
    }
    public function changeSection(section:String):void {
        currentSection = section;
        setupSection(currentSection);
    }
    public function setupSection(section:String):void {
        // setup section
    }
}
```

Now you can use your `Main` class from anywhere like you currently are doing, like this:

```
Main.main.changeSection("loadNext");
```

I should mention, though, that is not generally considered a good design, because you are globally coupling your code to `Main`. This gets messy and harder to expand on, as you've already discovered in a small sense. A better solution is to use events or [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

---

Using events is a little more setup, but it's typically much cleaner and less problematic in the long run. I've never regretted refactoring deeply coupled code into events.

First, you can define a nice little custom event class that tells you a section should change (you don't always need a custom event class, you can use the generic `Event` class, but a custom class lets you define custom data for the event):

```
public class SectionEvent extends Event {
    public static var SECTION_CHANGE:String = "sectionChange";
    public var section:String;
    public function SectionEvent(type:String, section:String){
        super(type, true); // bubbles=true, important later
        this.section = section;
    }
}
```

Now you can listen for this event and handle it in your `Main` class (which I'm assuming is a document class):

```
class Main extends MovieClip {
    public function Main(){
        addEventListener(SectionEvent.SECTION_CHANGE, sectionChangeHandler);
    }
    private function sectionChangeHandler(event:SectionEvent):void {
        changeSection(event.section);
    }
    public function changeSection(section:String):void {
        currentSection = section;
        setupSection(section);
    }
    private function setupSection(section:String):void {
        // setup section
    }
}
```

Now to change the section, simply dispatch the event (from any child display object of `Main`, it will bubble up since we set bubbles=true) like this:

```
dispatchEvent(new SectionEvent(SectionEvent.SECTION_CHANGE, "nextSection"));
```

Hopefully you can see that even though this adds a little extra code, it organizes it much better. It makes `Main` look very approachable, describes the action through an event very clearly, and isn't hard to understand and use. Each part of the flow is a tightly [encapsulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) piece of code that you can understand, expand, and test easier than before.

Comment: You beat me to it :), I was just getting ready to write an answer. One thing though, I believe that `setupSection` is a function inside of `Main`, so passing the instance of the child would not solve the issue.

Comment: Oh, I thought he was saying `changeSection` was called from `Main`, not that it was defined in `Main`... I think you're right after re-reading it. Updated my code example. (@esadude, can you please post your class statements with your code or make it clear what function is defined where?)

Comment: Hm, now that I see @esadude is calling a static main function, I see why your comment was suggesting a re-design. Passing an instance of `Main` is probably not what he wants to do. Expanding my answer...

Comment: Thank you for all the input, I understand why it causes problems, a potential duplicate in the initial option I chose. I'm looking at all input, but with @DodgerThud - var s:Section = //yadayada, I'm right in assuming that the Section is my respective new section. Before It completely loads, I get an error from the child so it must be on the event as it loads up the right class to beging with : Error #1069: Property sectionname not found on flash.events.Event and there is no default value.

var e:Event = new Event(Event.CHANGE);
e['sectionname'] = //the desired section ?
dispatchEvent(e);

Comment: @Aaron - I'll have a deeper look into what you kindly offered later.

Initially I hoped to have a listener on the 'section' variable and trigger the section load/reload on that but I gave up as I couldn't get that working. Dodger's option seemed a little closer to what I hoped could be done, but sometimes when you spend so long on it and it seems like it's simple, you lose rational thought. 1 day lost wrestling with this and just frustrated by the difficulty in which some things become with it!

Answer (score 0):

As @Aaron pointed out in his answer (and my initial comment), static functions/properties are not associated with an instance of a class.

To explain this more thoroughly, I will give an example. Lets say we have a class called `Main` and a class called `Section`.

```
class Section extends Sprite{
    public Section(){}

    public function a():void{
        //this is a function of an instance
    }

    public static function b():void{
       //a static function of the class
       a();//this will not work
    }
}

class Main extends Sprite{
    public Main(){
        var first:Section = new Section();
        var second:Section = new Section();
    }
}
```

As you can see, our Main class creates two instances of our Section class. For every instance you have, space is cleared in your RAM for all your properties and functions. So both `first` and `second` each have their own little space in your RAM. Both of them also possess a function called `a()`, because non-static functions/properties are associated to their instance. But what about the function `b()`? Well, this one exists indepent from any instance, and only exists **once** in your Ram.

So, when you try to do something like this

```
first.b();
```

I guess you assume that the function `a()` of the `first` instance is called. But this isn't possible because the static function doesn't know what `a()` you're referring to, it could be either `first` or `second` because `b()` exists **outside** them.

Hopefully my explanation is easy to understand :)

---

But lets actually solve your issue, without any static functions. As mentioned in one of my comments, you could (should?) use Events here. I will forego the Custom Event Shenanigans and will instead provide a more simple (but more hacky) solution.

In your `setupSection()` function, you probably do something like this

```
public function setupSection(sectionHolder:String):void{
    var s:Section = //you get the appropiate child instance somehow
    addChild(s);
}
```

What you need to do is to **listen** to Events that are dispatched from this instance, which would look like this:

```
var s:Section = //yadayada
s.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onSectionChange);
addChild(s);
```

In your Child class, when you want to change the Section, instead of calling a static function, you do this

```
var e:Event = new Event(Event.CHANGE);
e['sectionname'] = //the desired section
dispatchEvent(e);
```

Now, after the Event has been dispatched, the function `onSectionChange` in your Main instance will be called. The appropiate function would look like this

```
private function onSectionChange(e:Event):void{
  var sectionname:String = e['sectionname'];
  setupSection(sectionname);
}
```

Comment: Ha, now you beat me... I just edited my answer with very similar thoughts. Either way, I agree events are definitely the way to go here.